# How to cross compile older version of GCC under Debian?

Tags: gcc, arm, compiler

I'm trying to build an older version of GCC toolchain for ARM under x86 because there is [a bug with GCC > v5 for Cortex-M0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88167). I'm following the combination of the following instructions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10662297/1952991
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/24559878/1952991

So my overall procedure is as follows:

```
# Download GCC-5.5.0 from https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html
VERSION="5.5.0"
tar xzf gcc-$VERSION.tar.gz
cd gcc-$VERSION
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
../gcc-5.5.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/embedded/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5.5.0 --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --target=arm-none-eabi
make -j$(nproc) # use all cores
make install
```

Then the following files are created under `~/embedded/arm-none-eabi-5.5.0/bin/`:

```
arm-none-eabi-c++  arm-none-eabi-gcc-5.5.0   arm-none-eabi-gcov
arm-none-eabi-cpp  arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar      arm-none-eabi-gcov-dump
arm-none-eabi-g++  arm-none-eabi-gcc-nm      arm-none-eabi-gcov-tool
arm-none-eabi-gcc  arm-none-eabi-gcc-ranlib
```

However, the following command fails:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m0 -O0 -ggdb (......)

Compiling crt0_v6m.S
as: unrecognized option '-mcpu=cortex-m0'
make: *** [/home/ceremcem/ChibiOS/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/rules.mk:253: build/obj/crt0_v6m.o] Error 1
```

I can verify that the command uses newly produced binaries:

```
$ which arm-none-eabi-gcc
/home/ceremcem/embedded/arm-none-eabi-5.5.0/bin//arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

This means that the newly compiled GCC toolchain does not accept the `mcpu` option. What could be wrong with building the GCC toolchain phase that causes `-mcpu=cortex-m0` option to fail?

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate cross-binutils? It’s `as` that’s complaining, and that’s part of binutils.

Comment: Yes and no. I'm already installed and using arm-none-eabi-gcc v7.3.1 so I assumed the rest of the dependencies are already satisfied by the v7.3.1 installation and `./contrib/download_prerequisites` command. Should I build something else?

Comment: What version of Debian are you using?

Comment: I'm using Debian Buster/sid (testing). I would like to achieve a distro agnostic solution though.

Comment: Right, I understand that, I was wondering since Debian 9 has `gcc-arm-none-eabi` version 5.4.1.

Comment: Current version where `arm-none-eabi-gcc -dumpversion` prints is `7.3.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your GCC doesn’t appear to be using the right `as`, and probably wouldn’t use the right `ld` either; you need to add

```
--with-as=/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld
```

to your `./configure` line.

You’re also likely to run into issues related to Debian’s multi-arch approach, which GCC 5 doesn’t support directly. Your best bet is to download [the last Debian package of GCC 5.5](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/gcc-5/5.5.0-12/) in source form, and use that (with patches) to build your cross-compiler. Then it will use the ARM C library which was installed as a dependency of the cross-GCC package you installed.

```
dget https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-debug/20180412T094604Z/pool/main/g/gcc-5/gcc-5_5.5.0-12.dsc
cd gcc-5-5.5.0
debian/rules patch
```

then configure and build as before. (Ignore the cross-building documentation in `debian/README.cross`.)

Comment: This didn't solve all issues but made the problem proceed to another step: Now it can't find `stdint.h` while compiling an application, very much like the problem I've faced 4 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23973971/1952991

Comment: That’s because it’s looking for headers in the upstream location, not in the multiarch location; see my updated answer for a fix.

Comment: No luck, very same issue persists. Note that the `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/include/` folder contains many `*.h` files but the `include` folder in newly compiled gcc installation location is *still* empty.